# Picturebox in c# and resize image extraction

Tags: c#, winforms

I have enabled resize mode(stretch) in the picturebox now when i am extracting the image it doesn't extract the image same size like picture box rather it is taking the original picture size... any method to extract the stretched image. I am more concerned with width and height.

Details
Winform 
c#
Visual studio 2013

Comment: Stretch does exactly what it says.. Stretches the displayed image. If you want to transform the image then you must do so on the image

Comment: Thank you @Sayse, but as the picturebox do stretching why cant i extract that image

Comment: You are doing, it doesnt stretch the source as your image would become distorted when stretching it to different aspect dimentions and thus screwing up the source

Comment: Okay i got your point. I could have used the code to transform the image but i thought as picturebox doing it so i can extract it from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(picturebox.width, pixturebox.height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            g.DrawImage(original_image, 0, 0, picturebox.width, 
                        pixturebox.height);
```

You actually create a new Bitmap with the current width and height of the PictureBox. Then, you can save the image:

```
    result.Save(filename);
```

Comment: Thank you @ChrisB either way it solved my problem... So +1 for you.